# Robospice configure server URL

Tags: android, robospice

I'm using Robospice to manage my API and I would like to implement a feature on my login screen which allows to change which server URL will be used in my app.

On this login screen activity I have different editText field: username, login and url (server) and a login button.

I've implemented m Robospice service:

```
public class MyRetrofitService extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://myUrl.com";

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
    public static final String PREF_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String PREF_URL = "url";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        addRetrofitInterface(MyInterface.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServerUrl() {
        // SharedPreferences return my current url saved by the user
        String serverUrl = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("url",BASE_URL);

        // I want to change this value
        return serverUrl;
    }
}
```

Here my login Activity:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

    public SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(MyRetrofitService.class);

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       spiceManager.start(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       spiceManager.shouldStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Initialise UI + sharedPreference
         ....
    }

   View.OnClickListener loginButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get data from UI EditText
            setUrl(urlAddress.getText().toString())
            login(usersname.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
        }
    };

    public void setURL(String url) {

       // Save login details in sharedPreferences
       Auxiliar.editor.putString(MyRetrofitService.PREF_URL, url);
       Auxiliar.editor.putString(MyRetrofitService.PREF_USERNAME, usersname.getText().toString());
       Auxiliar.editor.putString(MyRetrofitService.PREF_PASSWORD, password.getText().toString());
       Auxiliar.editor.commit();

       Intent myservice = new Intent(this, MyRetrofitService.class);
       stopService(myservice);

       spiceManager.shouldStop();
       spiceManager = new SpiceManager(MyRetrofitService.class);
       spiceManager.start(getBaseContext()); // at this point should trigger getServerURl() in my RobospiceService but it doesn't
    } 

    private void login() {
       LoginService loginRequest = new LoginService(username, password);
       spiceManager.execute(loginRequest, new HTTPRequestListener());
    }
}
```

So what I'm doing is to stop my SpiceManager service and restart this service to force to trigger this getServerURL method in MyRetrofitService class and change the url.

I checked and this service is really stopped and than restarted but it didn't trigger getServerURl() to change this url.

Am I doing something wrong ? Do you have an idea to change this URL and save the new one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RetrofitSpiceService`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/extensions/robospice-retrofit-parent/robospice-retrofit/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/retrofit/RetrofitSpiceService.java) is not designed for a requirement like that (see code for details).

I would suggest either overriding the `getRetrofitService()` method and provide an implementation which is going to build a separate `RestAdapter` for each different server URL or implementing your own `RetrofitSpiceService` similar to the existing implementation but addressing your needs.